# Matrix theory (differential equations)

Tags: matrices

Let $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ be non-singular matrices. Is it true that if $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ don't commute, then $A(t)$ and $e^{B(t)}$ don't commute? If so, could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

**Oops** I gave a counterexample where $A$ was singular. Fixed:

The notation in the question is at least curious; it's just a question about two matrices, the fact that $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are functions of $t$ is irrelevant.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\pi i$, where $i=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $AB\ne BA$ but $Ae^B=e^BA$. (In calculating $e^B$ use the fact that $i^2=-I$.)